# Design View error: Constructor on type not found

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-forms-designer

I have a C# Visual Studio 2012 Windows Forms app which includes a UserControl (UcCLReferenteTecnico) inheriting from another class (WzNuovoClienteStepBase).

Example:

```
//my UserControl
public partial class UcCLReferenteTecnico : WzNuovoClienteStepBase
    {
        public UcCLReferenteTecnico(EvoClienteWz aiClienteWz, string aiCodLinea)
            : base(aiClienteWz, aiCodLinea)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            SetParameters(aiClienteWz,aiCodLinea)         
        }
    }

public EvoClienteWz _ClienteWz = new EvoClienteWz();
public class WzNuovoClienteStepBase : EvolutionBaseUC
    {
        public WzNuovoClienteStepBase(EvoClienteWz aiEvoClienteWz,
        string  aiCodLinea)              
        {
            _ClienteWz = aiEvoClienteWz;
            string wCod = aiCodLinea;
        }

public class EvolutionBaseUC : XtraUserControl, IEvolutionControl
{
 //implementation of this class
}
```

the problem that is when i try to open UcCLReferenteTecnico in VisualStudio's Design View mode, I receive the following error:

```
   Constructor on type 'EvoBoAnagraficaWz.WzNuovoClienteStepBase' not found.
```

Note: the project compiles and runs perfectly;

In view designer the instance of this error call stack is:

```
at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder 
binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.DesignSurface.CreateInstance(Type type)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.VSDesignSurface.CreateInstance(Type type)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.DesignerHost.System.ComponentModel.Design.IDesignerHost.CreateComponent(Type componentType, String name)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.DesignerSerializationManager.CreateInstance(Type type, ICollection arguments, String name, Boolean addToContainer)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.DesignerSerializationManager.System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.IDesignerSerializationManager.CreateInstance(Type type, ICollection arguments, String name, Boolean addToContainer)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.TypeCodeDomSerializer.Deserialize(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeTypeDeclaration declaration)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager manager)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.BasicDesignerLoader.BeginLoad(IDesignerLoaderHost host)
```

i tried to subsitute EvolutionBaseUc directly with XtraUserControl in this way:

```
 public partial class UcCLReferenteTecnico : XtraUserControl
    {}
```

to avoid inheriting from another class again but the error is the same.

N.B. in my windows form,I create UserControl (UcCLReferenteTecnico) using acitvator in this way:

```
WzNuovoClienteStepBase wCtrl = Activator.CreateInstance(t, new object[] { _EvoClienteWz, wCodLinea }) as WzNuovoClienteStepBase;
```

how can i avoid this designer error?

Comment: thanks it works, if you write it like an answer i will mark it as correct